# How to elegantly prove independence of gaps in infinite coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

Let $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p \in (0,1)$ and with values in $\{0,1\}$.

Let $G_1 = \min \{k \ge 1 | X_k = 1\}$, $G_n = \min \{k > G_{n-1} | X_k = 1\}$ for $n \ge 2$.

So we can say that $G_n$ represents the index of the $\textrm n$'th $1$ in the random sequence.  $G_n - G_{n-1}$  represents 1+#zeros between each 1.

My intuition tells me that the $(G_n - G_{n-1})_{n \ge 2}$ are i.i.d. I want to prove this.
However I have trouble writing a proof of independence efficiently.

In such a situation what is a concise and formal way to prove that the $(G_n - G_{n-1})_{n \ge 2}$ are mutually independent?

Comment: Hint: the Bernoulli process is "memoryless". We can ignore any number of trials from the start, and the tail of the process has the same distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process#Definition In fact, we can focus in on any infinite subset of the trials, ignoring the rest, and this subset will have the same distribution as the whole process.

Comment: I think now I have a proof of independence but its kind of tedious to write. I have to use conditional expectations and tower property to fix the random indices. I get long formulas but nothing conceptually very difficult. It's annoying that things like that for which intuition is clear seem like they can't be proven in just one line or two. I'll write an answer later unless someone has a short proof.

Comment: A better question is, how could they be dependent?? They are related to what happens in non-overlapping groups of trials, any two of which are independent.

Comment: This does not appear to be a very straightforward situation. The $G_1$ variable is obviously a usual Geometric Type I, but the subsequent $G$ variables are only conditionally defined since their _support_ depends on the realizations of the previous $G$ variables.